# One time date to be allowed in android

Tags: php, android

Hi In My Application I have one form with date field.Now If I click the submit button I want to show Toast message already date exist in database.

Suppose today dates I was selected then next click the submit button I am displaying some values.Now If I selected same date I don't want to allow that date.Means One time that date I want to accept for next time means I don't want to allow to next page.

can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just concept. You just add one more filed in your table like date_selected. And put 0 as default. When the user will select the date then just update the 0 to 1 for that date. 0 Suppose,means not selected. 1 means selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one more field in your sqlite table. So that whenever the user will select the correspond date then you have to put the flag for that date. And while accessing the date you can distinguish that the date has been already selected or not.